# Why does accessing an indexed item on an object work without noImplicitAny?

Tags: typescript

Why does this code compile?

```
interface RotationDirection {
    polarity: number,
}

const d: RotationDirection = {
    polarity: 1,
}

console.log(d[0]);
```

If I add `--noImplicitAny`, it fails with `PipeGenerator.ts:9:13 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type '{ polarity: number; }'.
  Property '0' does not exist on type '{ polarity: number; }'.`

I don't know how this could possibly be inferred to `any`. `d` clearly does not have a property 0, nor does the interface.

Comment: object fields work like an array, so you can iterate them or use with an indexer

Comment: Is that to say index expressions suppress property checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically it looks like bracket access was a "back door" to allow arbitrary property indexing when the compiler doesn't know if a property exists or not; see [microsoft/TypeScript#7660](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7660) and [microsoft/TypeScript#7733](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7733).

Note that in both dotted and bracketed access, the compiler infers that the type of the unknown property is `any`:

```
const any = d.notPresent; // unknown property error
// const any: any;
const alsoAny = d["notPresent"]; // implicitly any error
// const alsoAny: any;
```

That might be surprising.  The issue is that just because a property is *not declared* on an object type, it doesn't mean that the property is *definitely absent*; it just means that the compiler *does not know about it*, and it could be anything if it is present.  Another way of saying this is that object types in TypeScript are not [exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  In this case, an object of type `RotationDirection` may actually have a property with key `"0"`:

```
const weirdDirection = {
    polarity: 100,
    "0": true
};

const cloakedWeirdness: RotationDirection = weirdDirection; // no error
```

So the compiler decides that the type of such undeclared properties is `any`.

---

As time goes on this back door access via brackets is less of an issue.  It is [recommended](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#new---strict-master-option) that one enable the `--strict` flag to get the maximum type safety from the compiler.  And since `--strict` includes `--noImplicitAny`, you should get an error for both ways of accessing unknown properties (although the exact error message will differ, of course).

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsxzMdIAiwUECOeyA3gLABQy9yADugDZxTBgCeAXMiAFcAtgCNoAGloBfWrQR4AzmGQATPhixkCREluQBeSrQZNW7Tr2QBGSTRk05i5QHcIRFYWKlcIA0boMzGwc3HxWAAzhtiYAROExfGBQAhDSANyyNPIgSsgILOhwANYQKgDqblAqIBAKCuqY2D6euj5+ru4t3nhpyAD0ffzoyNBQ6FCZ2blwIFx+KgB0IJgACsQKEOC9A8gCIEXLzr6MY4zQ3CNQYxM0O1PKM5aPjjkPLAroAIKz8wDaMcswGtapswDEALrbQbAISMFjABCcFhzR6Xa60O5OZBwd5fWZ8Z4OOhAA)